# How do I hide a collection of HTML elements until the page is done loading?

Tags: javascript, pageload

I saw another question asked on Stack about not showing a page until its fully loaded.  That isn't quite what I'm asking here. What I want to do is wait to show one form until the page is entirely loaded. Is that possible? If so, how? Please provide some example code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this by setting display:none on the actual form and then using jquery to display it when the page is loaded.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#your_form_id').show();
  });
</script>

<form id="your_form_id" style="display:none;">
<!-- your content -->
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for detailing it out Krister.  Is there anything else I need to do?  Do I need to include or call jquery?  I've never used jquery before so I'm not sure.  But I tried your code and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should not listen to me and do the `display: none` trick.

---

You will need to create a JavaScript function that will create your form and inject it into the page. You will then need to register this function with the `domready` event.

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-domready

Example function that creates a form and injects it:

```
var createForm = function () {
    var form = document.createElement("form");

    var textBox = document.createElement("input");
    textBox.setAttribute("type", "text");
    textBox.setAttribute("name", "someText");
    form.appendChild(textBox);

    var submit = document.createElement("input");
    textBox.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    textBox.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
    form.appendChild(submit);

    document.getElementById("PUTFORMHERE").appendChild(form);
};
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
    <head />
    <body>
        <div id="PUTFORMHERE" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to the style="display:none" and then use jquery to show in on load.?

like $().load(function(){$('from').show();})

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it using the body onLoad attribute and JQuery. Something like this...

```
<body onLoad="$('#theform').show()">

<form id="theform" style="display:none">
<!-- blah blah blah -->
</form>

</body>
```

Hope this helps.